# Excel VBA - Click a specific pixel location in an open IE window

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, excel, pixel

I have an existing macro that navigates to a web page in an existing IE window. is there any way i can instruct excel to click on a specific pixel location?

here is the plain english template for what i would like to accomplish

```
ie.navigate "somesite.com"

with ie.document
     ie.click pixel 500,500
end with
```

Answer (score 0):

1, install Autoit
2, add reference to AutoitX.dll (tools--reference--browse and navigate to AutoitX.dll)
3. add this sinppet to your code

```
Set x = CreateObject("AutoItX3.Control")
X.MouseClick "left", 500, 500
```